# Jquery datatable bind from parameterized webservice

Tags: datatables

everything is fine i get json result but it is not biding result with datatable please help

json rsult:[{"OurBranchID":"8001","AccountID":"90186772","ProductID":"CA-PKR"}]{"d":null}

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'AccountService.asmx/GetAccountparam',
            data: "{ 'account': '90186772'}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var datatableinstance = $('#datatb').dataTable({

                    data: data,
                   // data: data.d,
                    columns: [
                { 'data': 'OurBranchID' },
                { 'data': 'AccountID' },
                { 'data': 'ProductID' },
                ]


                });
               
                $('#datatb tfoot th').each(function () {

                    var title = $('#datatb thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text"  placeholder="Search ' + title + '"/>');


                });

                datatableinstance.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var datatablecolumn = this;
                    $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {

                        datatablecolumn.search(this.value).draw();

                    });

                });

            }



        });


    });

 
  
  
    



</script>
```

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CopyJqueryajaxcallwithparameter.aspx.cs" Inherits="CopyJqueryajaxcallwithparameter" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'AccountService.asmx/GetAccountparam',
            data: "{ 'account': '90186772'}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var datatableinstance = $('#datatb').dataTable({

                    data: data,
                   // data: data.d,
                    columns: [
                { 'data': 'OurBranchID' },
                { 'data': 'AccountID' },
                { 'data': 'ProductID' },
                ]


                });
               
                $('#datatb tfoot th').each(function () {

                    var title = $('#datatb thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text"  placeholder="Search ' + title + '"/>');


                });

                datatableinstance.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var datatablecolumn = this;
                    $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {

                        datatablecolumn.search(this.value).draw();

                    });

                });

            }



        });


    });

 
  
  
    



</script>

<table id="datatb" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>OurBranchID</th>
<th>AccountID</th>
<th>ProductID</th>
</tr>

</thead> 
<tfoot>
           <tr>
<th>OurBranchID</th>
<th>AccountID</th>
<th>ProductID</th>
</tr>
        </tfoot>

</table>


</asp:Content>
```

webservice method:

[WebMethod]
     public void GetAccountparam(string account)
     {
         DataTable dtrsl;
         List lstacc = new List();
         dtrsl = cls.AccountDetailparam(account);

```
     foreach (DataRow row in dtrsl.Rows)
     {
         Account a = new Account();


         a.OurBranchID = row[0].ToString();
         a.AccountID = row[1].ToString();
         a.ProductID = row[2].ToString();

         lstacc.Add(a);

     }

     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    // Context.Response.Write(lstacc);
     Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(lstacc));




 }
```

Comment: You have posted invalid JSON, please inspect the actual response and post it "as is".

Comment: [{"OurBranchID":"8001","AccountID":"90186772","ProductID":"CA-PKR"}]{"d":null}

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. I'm not C# expert but it seems you generate your response incorrectly.